# Замена 19h (перезагрузка DOS) на свой с возвратом

Tags: ассемблер, прерывания, tasm

После вывода измененного прерывания (вопрос, хотели бы перезагрузиться?), не возвращает значения старого прерывания обратно. Он должен после того как я нажму 1, выполнить  reboot 
Работаю в TASM, вот пример моего кода

```
    .386
dseg segment use16
    text1 db 13,10,'Y 1t res? y1/n0 $'
dseg ends
cseg  segment use16
assume ds:dseg, cs:cseg
m1:
mov cx, dseg
mov ds, cx
; читаем из вектора 19 табл.прерыв. 4 байта и сохр. их в стек (прямое обращение)
mov ax,0
mov es,ax
mov di, 19h
shl di,2
mov bx, di
mov ax, [di+2]

push bx
push ax

; записываем в 19 вектор табл. перыв. адрес своей процедуры

lea dx,textart
mov es:bx,dx
mov dx,cs
mov es:[bx+2],dx

; вызов нашей процедуры
int 19h
    cmp al,31h

jne short m2 ; если не равно 1, то просто завершаем

; запишем в табл.прерыв. сохраненные адреса ранее
pop bx
pop ax
mov [di],bx
mov [di+2], ax
int 19h
m2:
mov ah,4ch; завершение программы
int 21h
textart proc
    mov ah, 9       ; выводим строку 
    lea dx,text1
    int 21h 
    mov ah,1h        ;ввод 0 или 1, по идее то что будет введено будет в AL
    int 21h
    iret
textart endp
cseg ends
end m1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот вроде написал
    .386
    dseg segment use16
        Message db 'Y 1t res? y1/n0 $'
        Answer db 2 dup(?)
    dseg ends
    cseg segment use16
    assume ds:dseg, cs:cseg
    m1: mov cx, dseg
        mov ds, cx

```
    mov al, 19h
    mov ah, 35h
    int 21h

    mov al,60h
    mov sp, es
    mov ds,sp
    mov dx,bx
    mov ah,25h
    int 21h; Перезаписали из 19h в 60h

    mov cx,cseg
    mov ds,cx
    lea dx,reboot

    mov al,19h
    mov ah,25h
    int 21h
    mov cx, dseg
    mov ds, cx
    int 19h
    mov ah,4ch
    int 21h

reboot proc
    lea dx, ds:Message
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h
    lea si, ds:Answer
    mov ah, 01h
    int 21h 
    cmp al, '1'
    jne short m3 ;если не равно
    mov al, 60h
    mov ah, 35h
    int 21h
    mov al,19h
    mov cx, es
    mov ds,cx
    mov dx,bx
    mov ah,25h
    int 21h
    int 19h     
m3:
    iret
reboot endp
cseg ends
end m1
```

Answer (score 0):

Первая же ошибка:

```
mov bx, di
mov ax, [di+2]
push bx
push ax
```

Что вы сохраняете в `bx`? Надо-то не `di`, а `[di]`...

Comment: угу, поменял. Только  теперь он мне выдал DOS ERORR, ax=604

Comment: Вообще не знаю что делать

Comment: Что делать - хороший вопрос. Особенно в контексте "нафига вообще это нужно" :) Как-то вот не видится use case для подобной ситуации. Для вывода запроса на перезагрузку подменять 19h совсем не нужно.Да и перегружать DOS можно проще...

Comment: К сожалению, в универе не дают делать произвольно, а только по заданию...

Comment: @papalimer В вашем варианте вы берете данные не из таблицы векторов, а из собственного кода по смещению di, потому как по умолчанию mov работает с сегментом ds. Вам надо _везде_ явно указывать сегмент `mov bx, es:[di]`. И не забудьте делать то же самое когда возвращаете значения обратно

Comment: @papalimer А вообще я думаю, что от вас ждут, что в случае согласия на перезагрузку ваш обработчик прерывания сам должен вызвать предыдущий обработчик, а не возвращать некое значение в вызывающий блок. Потому как обычно прерывания так себя и ведут - работают независимо от вызывающей программы, которая не ожидает от прерываний никакого нестандартного поведения, типа возврата значений не описанных в документации на эти прерывания